# get value from radio button list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a signup.aspx page with a radio button list

```html
            <asp:radiobuttonlist id="kita1" runat="server">
        <asp:listitem id="option1" runat="server" value="first" />
        <asp:listitem id="option2" runat="server" value="second" />
        <asp:listitem id="Listitem1" runat="server" value="third" />
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

and I need to get the value of the selected item and save it to a variable

how can I do that with javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
          RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="flow" >
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text ="Yes" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem  Text ="No" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>    </form>
<p id="button" onclick="getvalue()">click me</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue(){
 alert($('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: how can I save it into a variable?

Comment: try this    
function getvalueofradiolist() {

            var radioButtonlist = document.getElementsByName("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>");
            for (var x = 0; x < radioButtonlist.length; x++) {
                if (radioButtonlist[x].checked) {
                    alert("Selected item Value "  + radioButtonlist[x].value);
                }
}

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 var list = document.getElementById("radios"); //Client ID of the radiolist
 var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
 var selected;
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
          selected = inputs[i];
          break;
       }
  }
  if (selected) {
       alert(selected.value);// use value
  }
```